# Electric field in a vacuum

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

By changing the magnetic field can we generate electric field in a vacuum ?

By the Faradays law of EMI if the magnetic field associated with a coil changes, current is induced in that coil

So if we change magnetic field in vacuum will a current be generated in a vacuum?

Answer (score 1):

*So if we change magnetic field in vacuum will the current generate in vacuum?*

An electric field in a region where there are no mobile charged particles (a vacuum) will mean that there will be no moving charged particles (no electric current flowing).

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing "field" and "current".

A variable magnetic field in vacuum will indeed induce an electric **field**.

In the absence of any particle in vacuum this field will have noting to **act on**. Therefore there will be no electric **current**.